# sql server doesn't work on windows 8 64bit

Tags: sql-server, failed-installation

I'm facing kinda weird problems. I installed windows 8 pro 64 bit then installed Visual Studio 2010, both working well. But the problem is in SQL server 2008 and SQL server 2012 installation. Both gives different kind of errors; sometime it says that version not matching. Then finally, I installed 2012. Had no login or windows authentication. I don't know why it never happened to me. Please suggest a correct link for installing SQL server on windows 8 64bit so I can use MANAGEMENT studio etc..

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Software installation/configuration is offtopic.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when installing SQL Server Express on Windows 8.1 pro. Just right click the installation executable (even if it's on a DVD, find the setup.exe or similar), go to Properties, Compatibility tab and use the compatibility for an older version of windows, like Windows 7.

Another option is to download the latest package from Microsoft. I was able to install the SQL Server 2008 **SP3** without compatibility settings. You could try SQL Server SP1 as well (I haven't tested this without compatibility settings).

Answer (score 0):

here you go
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562

in there there's information about installing the old sql server apps on newer windows version. The minimum version for windows 8 is SQL Server 2008 SP3.